# RavenDB only via http?

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, ravendb

I am trying to learn RavenDB and using it's .Net client. If I am not wrong I think the main reason to use NoSql database like RavenDB is speed. It seems to be very fast as it is not relational. However when I am trying to play with .Net client of RavenDB I find that all calls are REST based calls. Doesn't that slow down speed? For each call of adding document it makes some call to HILO which basically lets the .Net client know which should be the next unique number to use and then it makes 2nd call to store the actual document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to be running RavenDB in a console app, and checking what happens in a very short lived fashion.
Run RavenDB in a real app over time, and you'll see that it is highly optimized for network usage.
You only see this hilo call once per X number of updates, and that X number changes based on your actual usage scenarios.
The more you use RavenDB, the faster it becomes.

Comment: Thank you. Is there Asp.Net MVC sample with RavenDB that I can follow?